# Why installed Lightshot under chrome openes strange popup content?

Tags: google-chrome

I need to install Lightshot under fresh kubuntu 22.04  and  in  Google Chrome
Version 117.0.5938.149 (Official Build) (64-bit))  I opened page
https://chrome.google.com/webstore/search/Lightshot

I selected  and installed Lightshot Pager

But selecting Lightsshot  icon I see strange :  https://prnt.sc/WaAmz6RNPbpk

Did I install invalid plugin ?

Answer (score 1):

It seems that you have installed the wrong extension for Lightshot. Lightshot Pager is not the official extension for taking screenshots, but a tool for browsing random images from the Lightshot service. The official extension for Lightshot is called Lightshot (screenshot tool), which you can find at this link https://app.prntscr.com/en/download.html. To use it, you need to drag the CRX file to the "Extensions" tab in Chrome and then click the button near the URL search bar. You can also download the desktop application for Lightshot from the same link.

Comment: Sorry, did not understand where can I get CRX file ?

Comment: The CRX file is the extension file for Chrome. You can get it from the link I provided, https://app.prntscr.com/en/download.html. Just scroll down to the section that says “Lightshot for Chrome” and click on the button that says “Download CRX”. Then, you can drag and drop the file to the “Extensions” tab in Chrome and follow the instructions to install it.

Comment: i do not see any “Lightshot for Chrome” section :  https://prnt.sc/fHBN6AGeB7pu
Do we way about same page?

Btw, I easily installed Lightshot for firefox...